# Is it possible to edit an animation built with Mixamo ?

Tags: animation, rigify

So I was doing a simple WalkCycle using Rigify but then I decided to do it using [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com) which seems way easier . I wonder if it's possible to edit graphs and dope sheets for Mixamo animation? For example I didn't like how the models hip moves so I want to change it a little bit, would it be achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export in Collada format from mixamo. When you import into blender, the animation should be editable.